# ExactTarget SOAP API: Sending an email to a single email address without a list or DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, send-email

Is this possible? I know i can start a send to an existing user initiated message using the perform action on the EmailSendDefinition object like below.

```
 <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Action>start</Action>
        <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">
                <CustomerKey>Send Email A</CustomerKey>
            </Definition>
        </Definitions>
    </PerformRequestMsg>
```

This works fine if the user initiated message has a list/DE with subscribers.

But i want to send to a single email address without using a list/DE.

I thought maybe adding the email element(below) on the soap call would do this but doesn't seem so.

```
<PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Action>start</Action>
        <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">
                <CustomerKey>Send Email A</CustomerKey>
                <Email>test@test.com</Email>
            </Definition>
        </Definitions>
```

Any ideas how i can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by setting up a triggered send.  You can do that completely by using the API, but I would recommend you do as much as you can within the application directly.  Have a look at [this triggered send guide](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/technical_library/web_service_guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers/).